# How to disable body parser json and urlencoded on certain urls?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, body-parser

```js
let shouldParseRequest = function (req) {
    let url = req.originalUrl;
    return (url.startsWith('/api/payments/stripe-webhook') || url.startsWith('/uploadimg'));
}
let parseJSON = bodyParser.json({ limit: '900kb' });
let urlencoded = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true})
app.use((req, res, next) => shouldParseRequest(req) ? parseJSON(req, res, next) : next())
```

So I had a question, how would I make the bodyParser json and urlencoded only run whenever the URLs don't include the ones above. I got this code from a github issue but I can't seem to make both of them run. Is there a better way to do this or how can I fix my current code?

Here is the github issue where I got the code from: https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser/issues/245

Comment: Maybe create 2 functions, and call them something more logical.  like `shouldParseJson`, and `shouldParseUrlencoded`.    You can stack multiple `app.use`'s.  A neater solution would be apply your middleware to your routes, just create another instance of APP and it can have any middleware's you want attached, and then just attach the app to your route.  eg.. `/json` could parse JSON, and `/encoded` etc could parse the other.. etc.  Another benefit is performance as each app only parses the middleware is requires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the below line in your code, if you have used it.

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

and use body-parser middleware on routes wherever it is needed like below code:

```
app.post('/', bodyParser.json(), (req, res) => {
    //...your code
})
```

If it is not needed in some routes you may skip it like below:

```
app.post('/url', (req, res) => {
    //...your code
});
```